# Convert localized percentage to float in Javascript

Tags: javascript, internationalization, type-conversion

I am using JavaScript's Number.toLocaleString() to convert decimal numbers to percentages for each locale I have. Depending on the locale, a number such as 0.5 will convert to "50%", "50 %" or "%50".

After the conversion is done and the user selects its option, I need to convert those strings back into decimals. JavaScript uses parseFloat() for this purpose which does ok in the first two cases but can't recognize the preceding percent and returns NaN for it.

For example:

```
>> parseFloat("50%")
<- 50
>> parseFloat("50 %")
<- 50
>> parseFloat("%50")
<- NaN
```

Is there a way to get the conversion working for all localized percentages? I know there can be other ways to sneak in the correct number in the background and not do any conversion, but at the time I'm not interested in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend doing any string manipulation on localized text, they should only be used for display purpose.

You need to keep pre-localized values, many html elements can display localized text and have value attribute for keeping the underlying values. E.g., if you are using "select":

```
<select>
    <option value="0.5">50 %</option>
    <option value="1">100 %</option>
    <option value="1.5">150 %</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something as simple as removing the %?

```
>> parseFloat("%50".replace('%', ''));
<- 50
```

This would work for any of the mentioned formats.